# Share Saved Search With Data Per User

Tags: netsuite, saved-searches

I am doing some practices in Netsuite, in which I have a saved search to see the tasks of each salesperson.

Now I would like that information to be seen by the user who captured it, in this case, we use partner as a sales executive, which is why I ask the question.

What option can help us see the tasks that each user with a Netsuite account has captured without seeing the others? Or it should be a search for every executive.

I appreciate your responses.